# How to use a trained Torch CNN model in Tensorflow

Tags: parameters, tensorflow, torch

I've done some convolutional neural network training for image classification in Torch for a year. I just started using Tensorflow recently. How can I reuse the trained Torch CNN model in Tensorflow for transfer learning? Is there any library for parameters transfer from Torch to Tensorflow? Or is there any suggestion for the format of parameters for sharing between Torch and Tensorflow?

I've tried saving parameters of each layer of a Torch model to a text file and copying them to Tensorflow as constant initialization.

examples:

```
conv_weights = tf.constant([0.17347207665443,0.11592379212379,0.026265326887369,0.12255407869816,-0.15566548705101,0.18516965210438,-0.045260231941938,0.13446696102619,0.15107157826424,0.0024442630819976,-0.03807720541954,-0.10220601409674,-0.17906428873539,0.10029320418835,-0.085617743432522,-0.015723343938589,-0.15337321162224,0.16704897582531,0.18761920928955,0.16804780066013,0.18608762323856,0.0048886127769947,0.12103436142206,0.088970154523849,0.050000578165054,0.092202171683311,0.11841697990894])
# Torch conv weights shape (output_dim, input_dim, width, height)
# Tensorflow conv weights shape (width, height, input_dim, output_dim )
# reshape to Tensorflow shape
conv_weights = tf.reshape(conv_weights, [1,3,3,3])
conv_weights = tf.transpose(conv_weights, [2,3,1,0])

kernel = tf.get_variable('weights', initializer=conv_weights, dtype=dtype)
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

This is probably enough if you want to check whether the results of Tensorflow and Torch are matching (use small model and manually copy weights). But this is not the best way for a proper transfer learning.

Comment: Kindly describe what you tried already and share your code here.